# Where can I put my functions login, logout, recover-password, register in an laravel api?

Tags: laravel, api, solid-principles

I have to build an api in Laravel, and I want to do it in the best possible way. My api will have the classic methods to log in, log out, recover password and register. Where can I put those functions and what would be the recommended routes for those?

I have the idea to put it like this:

`POST mywbsite.com/api/v1/user/login` -> Login

`POST mywbsite.com/api/v1/user/logout` -> Log out

`POST mywbsite.com/api/v1/user/recover-password` -> Recover password

`POST mywbsite.com/api/v1/user/store` -> Register

And in my controller user I would have methods like these:
`login()`, `logout()`, `recoverPassword()`, `store()`

But I think this would go against one of the SOLID principles. Since I read somewhere that a driver in this case Laravel would only have to have the methods store, update, create, destroy and edit

And as I am half confused how can I do it in the best way.

Comment: Sounds solid and thoughtfully organized to me. Some like to use request verbs to differentiate the controller method - POST, DELETE, PUT but here the words matter and the extra clarity will help other devs on the project (or those consuming your api) easily differentiate between endpoints. If any one method becomes too complex, it could become an issue; but, having everything related to authentication (at a high level) right there is very reasonable and follows several best practices patterns.

Comment: Thanks, 
Laravel has an Auth folder, where those methods are.
Organized like this: `Auth / LoginController.php` `Auth / RegisterController.php` `Auth / ForgotPasswordController.php` `Auth / ResetPasswordController.php`. Now my routes are: `mywebsite.com/api/v1/auth/login` `mywebsite.com/api/v1/auth/logout` `mywebsite.com/api/v1/auth/recover-password` `mywebsite.com/api/v1/auth/register`